# Comparing pictures in JAVA

Tags: java, image-processing

I've run into a problem where i try to compare some pictures and if they equal, the program does some certain things. When i test it on the computer i've made the program on it has no problem comparing the pictures. (I run 1920x1080). But when i try to run the same program on a different computer with smaller monitor, but same resolution it doesn't work. The second computer still compares a picture of the exact same thing, size etc. only difference is that the original picture it compares the newly taken picture to, is the one taken on my original computer. Are there any differences between taking pictures of the desktops from computer to computer? I'm not sure how i should fix this. Right now i'm just taking pictures of certain pixels, and use the pixelgrabber to compare.

```
public static boolean processImage(String file1) {

    String file2 = "screencapture.png";

    Image image1 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(file1);
    Image image2 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(file2);

    int[] data1 = null;
    int[] data2 = null;

    try {

        PixelGrabber grab1 = new PixelGrabber(image1, 0, 0, -1, -1, false);
        PixelGrabber grab2 = new PixelGrabber(image2, 0, 0, -1, -1, false);

        if (grab1.grabPixels()) {
            int width = grab1.getWidth();
            int height = grab1.getHeight();
            data1 = new int[width * height];
            data1 = (int[]) grab1.getPixels();
        }

        if (grab2.grabPixels()) {
            int width = grab2.getWidth();
            int height = grab2.getHeight();
            data2 = new int[width * height];
            data2 = (int[]) grab2.getPixels();
        }

        System.out.println("Pixels equal: " + java.util.Arrays.equals(data1, data2));

    } catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    return java.util.Arrays.equals(data1, data2);
}
```

Comment: Show you code for how are comparing.

Comment: You did not compare for width and height of images before extracting the pixels. If they are not same, you may want to scale and compare them depending upon your need.

Comment: @SureshKoya check my answer to the question :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it doesn't work is somehow because the picture i take on the other computer becomes brighter than the original. However, not sure how to fix yet.

Comment: You may trying limiting the number of colors to 256 in your Original and use the same no of colors in your test computer to avoid discrepencies.

Comment: @SureshKoya How do i do that?